# How NSMutableSet added object to keep unique?

Tags: objective-c

when we use MutableSet to add a object, to keep object unique, achieve `-(NSUInteger)hash` and `-(BOOL)isEqual:(id)object` method, I don't know when the two method will be called?

Comment: So why do you want to know that? What is the exact problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, whether I understand your Q correctly. However, …

A. You should not care about the time, the methods are called. What for? Whether an object is equal to another object does not depend on the time, it is tested. (Unless the object changed meanwhile.)

B. A `-hash` difference is not necessary for uniqueness. To *different* objects may have the *same* hash value. As you will see soon, this is usual.

C. It is an urban legend that `NSSet` or `NSMutableSet` guarantees uniqueness. Both check for uniqueness, when you insert an object. But it does not (and cannot) check, if an inserted object changes its values so it becomes equal to another one *after inserting*.

```
NSMutableString *amin = [@"Amin Negm-Awad" mutableCopy];
NSMutableString *firstname = [@"Amin" mutableCopy];
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObjects:amin, firstname];
[firstname appendString:@" Negm-Awad"];
```

Obviously both strings are in the set and both strings are equal.

The guarantee of uniqueness only can be made, if the members of the set (not the set itself) are immutable.

D. Ah, immutability of the members: An object's hash value is not allowed to change, when it is a member of a collection. Beside the fact, that it is impossible to detect, whether an object is member of a collection, outside a collection `-hash` has little meaning.

That means for mutable objects, that you cannot implement `-hash` in dependency of the properties of the object: Since the properties of a mutable object can change, this would change the hash value.

Moreover, since the hash value of an object das to be equal for equal objects, you cannot set the hash value at initialization to a more or less random number. You cannot know, if the objects becomes equal to another one, but in such a case you have to guarantee hash equity.

To make the log story short:

1. If the members of the set are mutable, don't care about great hash algorithms. Simply return a hash value which is constant for all instance objects of that class. This is poor, but every other solution breaks.
2. In `-isEqual:` simply compare the properties of the objects. It should not depend on the time, the test is run.

Comment: Thank you.I think this is not my needs,you mislead my Q. if I create Class MONInteger, add to NSMutableSet, create simlar instance twice,if I log,there is two object .

Comment: So, please rephrase your Q.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear, so here is a guess:

In a comment you wrote:

> if I create Class MONInteger, add to NSMutableSet, create simlar instance twice,if I log,there is two object

If you define a class which you wish to insert into a set, or do any other operation which requires equality, you need to define `hash` and `isEqual` methods in the class, something like:

```
@implementation MONInteger

- (NSUInteger) hash
{
   //  ...
}

- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)object
{
   // ...
}

// other methods of the class

@end
```

The basic logic these two methods must implement are:

1. `isEqual` should return `YES` if (and only if) it argument, `object`, is an instance of `MONClass` and the current object (`self`) and `object` represent the same `MONClass` value (not the same `MONClass` object).
2. `hash` *must* return the the same value for objects for which `isEqual` returns `YES`. It *may* return the same value for objects which are not equal, but it is better if it the number of distinct values it returns is large and well spread. (If that is not clear then look up hash algorithms.)

The above methods will be called when an object is added to a set, both on the object being inserted and on objects already in the set. However this is not an important point, they are called when needed and how they are written does not depend on when they are called. I suspect your language is misleading here and you did not intend to ask this (not being negative here, my Mandarin/Cantonese, which I expect is your first language, is non-existent!)

If you get two distinct `MONInteger` objects in your set when they represent the same value then either you have not implemented `hash` and `isEqual`, or you have implemented them incorrectly so the do not provide a correct equality check.

HTH

Comment: Thank you very much! You anwer explain my confused entirely.